# Downloaded PDF in iPad has name of the Servlet. How can this be fixed

Tags: java, servlets, itext

I am generating PDF from HTML, everything works fine in all the browsers but in iPad when we download the PDF, it saves with the name of the Servlet.

my response headers are:

```
response.setHeader("Cache-Control","private");
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" +docTitle+".pdf" + "\"");
```

Please let me know if I am missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by doing     document.setTitle("name")

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to download the file? From safari? Did you try setting the content-type also? (It needs to go before the content-disposion)

```
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
```

(or also try "application/octet-stream")

Some browsers in the past (mostly IE) had problems with the filename. Is it possible for you to change your url? Simply append a forward slash and the filename to the url like /yourpage.html/docTitle

Comment: It doesn't need to go before the content-disposition. ["The order in which header fields with differing field names are received is not significant."](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt)